# Why flatten dosen't work and compiler inferring as object for inner list

Tags: scala, list, flatten

Why flatten doesn't work below why compiler is inferring values as objects instead of specifically making a list.

```scala
val suits = List("spades", "hearts", "dimonds", "clubs")

val values = ((2 to 9 by 1) map (x => String.valueOf(x))).toList

val numbers = ("ace" :: values :: List("jack", "queen", "king")).toList

println(numbers.flatten)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `List` method `::` is used to pre-pend an element to a `List`. It can not be used to concatenate two lists together. You can use `:::` or `++` for that.

```
val numbers = "ace" :: values ::: List("jack", "queen", "king")
```